# Error while loading csv file to Snowflake Table as "Timestamp '9/15/2020 1:28:00 AM' is not recognized"

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-task, snowsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

csv_file:

```
|column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3             |
|===========================================|
|abc      | xyz      | 9/15/2020 1:28:00 AM |
```

I am trying to load a file from s3 to snowflake using following command:

```sql
COPY INTO  table_name 
FROM @stage/file_name.csv  
FILE_FORMAT = (
   type = csv 
   SKIP_HEADER = 1
) 
FORCE = TRUE 
ON_ERROR = Continue;
```

but while executing this query getting error as **Timestamp '9/15/2020 1:28:00 AM' is not recognized**.
Is there any way so that I will be able to load the data to table without getting any error ?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake tries to automatically detect the timestamp format of files loaded if you don't explicitly specify it. Sometimes date strings however can match multiple input formats so Snowflake [can't guarantee](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#supported-formats-for-auto-detection) that the date is parsed as you intended.

You can either set the [TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-input-format) session parameter before loading to 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' or you can specify it as a `file_format` option like below (untested):

```sql
COPY INTO table_name 
FROM @stage/file_name.csv 
FILE_FORMAT = (
      type = csv 
      SKIP_HEADER = 1 
      TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'
   ) 
FORCE = TRUE ON_ERROR = Continue;
```